# Is it possible to obtain the degree centrality values based on the node attributes using Networkx and Python?

Tags: python, attributes, nodes, networkx

I'm new to Networkx and I would like to know if there's any way to output the following:

> Let's say I have a network whose nodes are people's names and their attributes are their gender(M,F).
> When obtaining the degree centrality
> degree_cent = nx.degree_centrality(g)
>
> Instead of having something like this:
>
> [('Anna', 1.0),('Ben',0.6), ...
>
> Is it possible to have something like this:
>
> [('Anna', M:0.4, F:0.6),('Ben', M:0.3, F:0.3),... where I can distinguish the number of nodes with M and F attributes that are connected to my nodes of interest?
>
> Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of a graph and your desired centrality values? How can degree centrality be floats instead of ints? Do you have weights in your graph?

Comment: I have an undirected protein-protein interaction network (no weights). In this network, the proteins can be grouped into different types, according to their attributes. So let's say in the network, I have proteins of the type A, B and C. I would like to get the degree centrality for each protein in the network but instead of only having the total number of connections to each protein, I would like to know how many proteins of types A, B and C are connected to them. Is this possible with Networkx? The floats would just be the normalised values. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own degree function:

```py
import networkx as nx
import random

random.seed(42)

graph = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(20, .1)

classes = ["A", "B", "C"]

for node in graph:
    graph.nodes[node]["attribute"] = random.choice(classes)


def attribute_degree(G, node):
    degree = {}

    for neighbor in G.neighbors(node):
        attribute = G.nodes[neighbor]["attribute"]
        degree[attribute] = degree.get(attribute, 0) + 1

    return degree


print(attribute_degree(graph, 0))
# {'B': 1, 'A': 2, 'C': 1}
print(attribute_degree(graph, 1))
# {'B': 1, 'A': 1, 'C': 1}
```